# Multi image's resolution development with WP

Tags: windows-phone, monogame

I am a beginner in WP development with Monogame, and I want to develop a universal WP app (All devices which run under WP).

Can you give me the different screen's resolution and **aspect ratio**?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

- 480 × 800, ratio 15:9, scale factor 1 — WVGA, the only one supported by WP7.x OS version
- 768 × 1280, ratio 15:9, scale factor 1.6 — WXGA
- 720 × 1280, ratio 16:9, scale factor 1.5 — 720p
- 1080 x 1920, ratio 16:9, scale factor 2.25 — 1080p

The resolution in “logical pixels” (after the scaling) is either 480×800 on 15:9 screens, or 480×853 on 16:9 screens.

[Source.](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windowsphone/develop/jj206974%28v=vs.105%29.aspx)